# Getting error when get object from aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

on my local get object working well, but i dunno when i run on production (ec2 - elasticbeanstalk) i have problem in console when getting object from s3

`[AWS S3 403 0.13824 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"test",:key=>"abcd.flv") AWS::S3::Errors::Forbidden AWS::S3::Errors::Forbidden`

anyone know ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same access information?

Comment: Hi datasage, thanks for your reply, my fault is very stupid, wrong access key, forgot to change access key for production. tnx anyway

Comment: Just for future reference, I had the same error and it was because the internal clock of my server was not synchronized :O.. a `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` made the trick.